# Using Html.DisplayNameFor within Html.ActionLink (MVC 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my razor view , am using @Html.ActionLink to display an hyperlink , and the text that gets displayed is hard coded( "Brand" in this case). model for the view is  @model IEnumerable

**Exisitng View**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Brand", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.BrandSortParm })
```

Instead of hard coding the text , would like to use @Html.DisplayNameFor as first parameter in  @Html.ActionLink , something like mentioned below , which is giving compile error

```
@Html.ActionLink(@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BRAND_NAME), "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.BrandSortParm })
```

Please let me know , how to do that.

Comment: Yes , "this one worked @Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BRAND_NAME).ToHtmlString(), "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.BrandSortParm }) . Thanks !!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need a string, so make it `ToHtmlString()`

```
@Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BRAND_NAME).ToHtmlString(), "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.BrandSortParm })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create helper class:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static string DisplayName<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
        {
            var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TValue>(expression, html.ViewData);
            return metadata.DisplayName;
        }
    }
```

Add a reference to your class in the view and then use it:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayName(model=> model.BRAND_NAME), "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.BrandSortParm })
```